# Robotframework - Selenium - How to verify page loaded completely (successfully) without relying on a specific element in the page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I was wondering if there is anything in Selenium that can verify if a page loaded completely without relying on a specific element in the page to appear (while using the "wait until page contains" or similar keywords).
The idea is reusability. If there is a need to add new websites to the robot automation later, I do not want to rely on a specific element that might exist in one page but not in another to verify if the page loaded fully.
Is there any keyword that addresses that in Robot Framework - Selenium Library?

Thanks!

Edit - I am aware that some AJAX requests are impossible or extremely difficult to conclude if they finished or not (or if they just keep going forever) so let's assume the website does not have any of that.
Once the page is finished loading, all requests are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find some built-in option but there is another way to achieve this. Check if your web app uses any third-party library which shows progress bar, if yes then probably there is function which returns the status of page loading including Ajax call. If not, then you can ask devs to add some progress bar, for instance Pace.JS

document.readyState does not wait for Ajax calls, personally I found it less helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
   driver.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
```

use execute script document.readyState , if it returns complete it means the loading have finiished.

But if there is no ajax you don't have to do it selenium does it automatically so your question won't be valid:

[https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/#:~:text=Defines%20the%20current%20session's%20page,loading%20takes%20lot%20of%20time](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/#:%7E:text=Defines%20the%20current%20session%27s%20page,loading%20takes%20lot%20of%20time).

> normal This will make Selenium WebDriver to wait for the entire page
> is loaded. When set to normal, Selenium WebDriver waits until the load
> event fire is returned.
>
> By default normal is set to browser if none is provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! Appreciate it!